# rapheal js Element.node.onclick() and Element.click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

hello i have just start using `Raphael` but i'm very confused in the following code

**WHY** this code works

```
            var paper = Raphael("canvas_container", 320, 200);
            var mycir = paper.circle(50, 40, 30);
            mycir.node.onclick = function() { alert("any thing") }
```

**AND** this doesn't

```
            var paper = Raphael("canvas_container", 320, 200);
            var mycir = paper.circle(50, 40, 30);
            mycir.click = function() { alert("any thing") }
```

i also tried and it didn't work :

```
            mycir.click(function(){alert("any thing")});
```

what the diffrence ? when i look at the raphaeal document they use `Element.click()` . why can't i use it them , is this is my version or What ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to assign to click, instead of calling it.
This should work:

```
        var paper = Raphael("canvas_container", 320, 200);
        var mycir = paper.circle(50, 40, 30);
        mycir.click(function() { alert("any thing") });
```

Note that Raphael recommends not to use `.node` (as it says: "Don’t mess with it.")

Comment: thanks for replying ... but i mention i tried this and it didn't work

Comment: I actually tried it in jsfiddle and it worked, but I did not save it! :( You need to click on the line of the circle for this to work, not easy with a one pixel line, have you tried increasing the stroke-width to make it more obvious?

Comment: well i just notice something weird ... if you add attr() to the circle() it works fine ??? which makes your comment about the pixel issue explains exactly what happening

Comment: Yes, an attr to set a larger stroke-width or a fill eliminates the difficulty of clicking on a very thin edge, which I think is the reason why you didn't see it working. But even without the attr, it should work if you manage to click the right pixel (zooming-in using your browser would help too, SVG is great that way)

Comment: could you please add this to your answer ... Thanks